# fedora linux : what does foldername blinking in red mean?

Tags: linux, fedora

I have this broken fedora linux server which runs unitrends which i have been assigned to fix.
the folder /usr/bp/data is highlighted in red and blinking when I do an 'ls' on it.

any ideas what this means?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Broken symlink.

[gnome-terminal screenshot http://maman.monnet.biz/img/brokenlink.png](http://maman.monnet.biz/img/brokenlink.png)

Yup, santaclaus does not exist.

(Probably blinking on terms that support it, gnome-terminal doesn't)

Comment: Funny while still answering the question and not being obnoxious, nice!!

Answer (score 1):

You should have a file /etc/DIR_COLORS. Look in there to see what color coding means what.

Answer (score 0):

To see where a link was pointing.  You can use ls -l or the readlink -f  command.